# in orleans, how get orleans reference by type?

Tags: orleans

for example，How to get grain by type instead of generic type:

```
var type = typeof(IGrainInterface1);
var grain = GrainClient.GrainFactory.GetGrain(type, Guid.NewGuid());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the grain is hidden behind the interface on purpose. You are supposed to expose the methods you need in the interface. If you only have one type implementing the interface, then you'll know that is the type you will get.

Also to get a reference to a grain you can use the `<>` notation to write it more concisely.

```
var grain = client.GetGrain<IGrainInterface1>(Guid.NewGuid());
```

The guid is used to identify a specific grain instance, so every time you call `GetGrain` with a new Guid, a new instance of the gran is created.

For more information, check out the [docs](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Getting-Started-With-Orleans/Developing-a-Client.html#making-calls-to-grains)